# Need help locating a sibling element error message to a specific select list

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a form with inputs that are usually dependents of divs. Under that div is also a span which will show an error message if the field is required but left empty.

However, on select lists, the span isnt under the same div as the input, its a sibling element to the div.

I am trying to write a test to verify the error message appears on the appropriate input if it is left blank, it was fairly easy on the other inputs as the are under the same parent, but with the select lists, I cant figure out how to confirm the span for the select list shows since its not under the same div as the select list input. Here is an html example of what im dealing with:

```
<form name="editorForm" novalidate="" class="ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" style="">

   <div class="select icon-arrow-down ng-scope" ng-if="!isCurrentSectionReadOnly">
        <select name="additionalPropertyType" ng-model="additionalPropertyCtrl.selectedExposure.additionalPropertyTypeExternalId" ng-options="additionalPropertyType.value as additionalPropertyType.text for additionalPropertyType in additionalPropertyCtrl.additionalPropertyTypes" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" style="">

   <span form-submitted="additionalPropertyCtrl.editorSaveAttempted" yp-field-error="editorForm.additionalPropertyType" class="ng-isolate-scope field-validation-error">
       <span name="errorMessage" class="">Please provide an Additional Property Type.</span></span>

 </form>
```

The span in the example should only be visible when the select list from the previous div is submitted while blank. **How do i verify this specific span is visible without using something brittle such as text or indexing? Is there a way to verify some kind of sibling relationship?**

I need a way to confirm the span specific to the select list from the div above it is visible and not just that a span like this is visible as the form may have more then one instance of this and each span has the same name. I want to avoid using specific text(as it may change) or index(also may change)

Comment: You might be able to use the `parent` method to move up (and then down) the DOM.  Check out this blogpost: https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/locating-an-element-based-on-its-siblings/

Comment: Ive read that, and moving thru a table is easy, the trouble im having is making sure its ONLY confirming the span specific to the input field. Xpath seems to have a way to do this. Ill post an answer of how i got it to work, and see if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: @orde, I also have a [post on locating sibling elements](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/locate-a-sibling-from-a-watir-element/).

Comment: this is a good example of where things could be made easier by getting your developers to add an attribute you can use to find the specific error message.  Or maybe restructure to make it a sibling of the select list, so it is a consistent pattern as with other error messages.   Might be worth bringing this to their attention and see what could be done to make it cleaner/easier

Comment: Yea, that was the first thing done, but because of styling on the select list, they could be under the same div(at least thats what i was told) and as for adding a unique id to each message..well..that requires someone else to do more work. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Traversing to Sibling**

You can get the sibling of an element by using XPath with `following-sibling` or `preceding-sibling`.

In this case, you are trying to find the following span relative to the div:

```
select_list = browser.select(name: 'additionalPropertyType')
parent_div = select_list.parent
sibling_span = parent_div.span(:xpath => './following-sibling::span')
sibling_span.text
#=> Please provide an Additional Property Type.
```

You can combine all of these calls into a single XPath. This will improve performance, but possibly at the cost of code readability.

```
browser.span(xpath: '//select[@name="additionalPropertyType"]/../following-sibling::span').text
#=> Please provide an Additional Property Type.
```

**Using Unique yp-field-error Attribute**

Given that the `yp-field-error` attribute on the `span` is unique, you can avoid the above complicated traversal. As this is non-standard HTML attribute, you will need to use XPath or CSS:

```
# Using XPath:
browser.span(xpath: '//span[@yp-field-error="editorForm.additionalPropertyType"]').text

# Using CSS:
browser.span(css: 'span[yp-field-error="editorForm.additionalPropertyType"]').text
```

Given that you have multiple select lists like this, you should add `yp_field_error` to the searchable attributes. This will allow you to write the usual locators without XPath/CSS. Update where you require Watir-Webdriver to be:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
Watir::HTMLElement.attributes << :yp_field_error
```

Your code for finding the element then simply becomes:

```
browser.span(yp_field_error: 'editorForm.additionalPropertyType').text
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing and it seems to work. I used "prop_type_element.parent.span_element(:xpath => './following-sibling::span[1]').visible?" Im not sure how your one line example finds the correct parent.

Comment: In XPath, the parent can be retrieved by the '..'

Comment: Is the `yp-field-error` attribute on the span unique? That might be a better solution and avoid having to build a complicated traversal. For example, I would guess that `browser.span(xpath: '//span[@yp-field-error="editorForm.additionalPropertyType"]')` might be sufficient.

Comment: It should be unique yes. each one has the input field name there. Im not very familiar with xpath, didnt know I could use that attribute in an xpath. That would give the span a unique identifier to search for.

Comment: Yes, the solution above also seems to work and is a tad bit cleaner. You can update your answer if you wish.

Comment: @Mayshar, I updated the answer to include that example, as well as an even cleaner solution (ie without XPath).

Comment: Accepted new answer. Oh, I also wasnt aware it was that easy to add an attribute to search by. Thats Awesome!!